# Android: CheckBox tree

Tags: android, checkbox, expandablelistview

In my application, I have a list and a button, in my list i want when i select parent item all of the child-item be selected indeed I want a Check-box tree. I use an Expandable List View but i have a problem in my code:

My code is: 
list_group.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:padding="8dp"
              android:background="#000000">


    <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:focusable="false"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</LinearLayout>
```

list_item2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="55dip"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:background="#ffffff">

    <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:focusable="false"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="17dip"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-40dp"
            android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

backup_list.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="#000000">

    <ExpandableListView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/expandableListView"/>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/backup"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="BackUp"
            android:clickable="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How can i fix it?

ExpandableListAdapter:

```
package com.mCloud.android.ui.activity;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.mCloud.android.R;

public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                                 HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item2, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition){
        return true;
    }
}
```

ParentActivity:

```
package com.mCloud.android.ui.activity;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import com.mCloud.android.Log_OC;
import com.mCloud.android.R;
import com.mCloud.android.filters.MediaFilenameFilter;

public class ParentActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "mCloudPreferences";
    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.backup_list);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSherlock().getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // get the listview
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);

        // preparing list data
        prepareListData();

        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);


        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
        Intent intent;

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), DisplayInfoActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            default:
                Log_OC.w(TAG, "Unknown menu item triggered");
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /*
     * Preparing the list data
     */

    private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataHeader.add("Files");
        listDataHeader.add("Apps");
        listDataHeader.add("SMS");
        listDataHeader.add("Contacts");
        listDataHeader.add("Call Logs");
        listDataHeader.add("Calender");
        listDataHeader.add("Setting");


        List<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();
        File file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        String[] list = file.list(new MediaFilenameFilter());
        if (list != null) {
            for (String name : list)
                files.add(name);
        }
        files.add("Advance Selection");

        List<String> apps = new ArrayList<String>();
        apps.add("All Apps");

        List<String> sms = new ArrayList<String>();
        sms.add("Inbox");
        sms.add("Draft");
        sms.add("Send");

        List<String> contacts = new ArrayList<String>();
        contacts.add("All Contacts");

        List<String> calllogs = new ArrayList<String>();
        calllogs.add("Resived");
        calllogs.add("Missed");
        calllogs.add("Dailed");

        List<String> calender = new ArrayList<String>();
        calender.add("All calender");

        List<String> setting = new ArrayList<String>();
        setting.add("All setting");

        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), files);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), apps);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), sms);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3), contacts);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(4), calllogs);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(5), calender);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(6), setting);

    }
}
```

Comment: well you didnt give us the actual code..only the layout, we cant help you without the java part. also, what is the actual problem? when you check the parent checkbox what happenes?

Comment: with this code when i select the parent checkbox none of the child item won't be selected, but i want all the child items be selected.

Comment: I need that code part..

Comment: you want to check all childs when pressing on parent checkbox right? where is the code for that part?

Comment: yes, my problem is that , i don't know how do this?

Comment: If you give me a screenshot i migh be able to help you..

Comment: image link is: http://i44.tinypic.com/euo745.png

Comment: when you press on the checkbox the parent expands and when you press on it again the parent collapses?

Comment: No, i want when check the parent child items be selected that now nothing is happen and that is my problem that how do this.

Answer (score 0):

but you do understand that ExpandableListView work like what I asked you..?
 when you press on parent the parent expands (unless you state otherwise) and when you clikc on it again the parent collapses..
 if you want to be able to expand the parent and also be able to check and uncheck the parent checkbox you need to give two views in the same row of the parent, the first is the checkbox and the second is the parent title (which can be empty like "")
they should be side by side.

you can do somthing like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/Rl11"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:background="@drawable/desserts_main_expand"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:cropToPadding="true"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ParentTextI"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/addIng"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Side_image"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:text="dummy text"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and then in the adapter:

declare a global variable

```
CheckBox checkbox;
```

**this is only for the parent checkbox part

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, 
      ViewGroup parent) {
checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(checkbox.isChecked()=true)
                      {checkbox.setChecked(false);}
                    else checkbox.setChecked(true);
                ParentActivity.checkall();
                }
            });
```

and then in ParentActivity:

add a function that checks every child of the same parent:

```
public static void checkall()
{
for(int j=0 ; j<files.size() ; j++)
 {if (listAdapter.checkbox.isChecked()==true)
 {files.get(j).setChecked(true)};
}
```

I have made the code specially for you so there might be some error cause i havnt checked it..
but it supposed to be somthing like this.